# SQL Query going for Full Table scan instead of Index Based Scan

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

I have two tables:

```
create table big( id number, name varchar2(100));
insert into big(id, name) select rownum, object_name from all_objects;

create table small as select id from big where rownum < 10;
create index big_index on big(id);
```

On these tables if I execute the following query:

```
select * 
  from big_table 
 where id like '45%' 
    or id in ( select id from small_table);
```

it always goes for a Full Table Scan.

```
Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 2290496975
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name  | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |       |  3737 | 97162 |    85   (3)| 00:00:02 |
|*  1 |  FILTER            |       |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| BIG   | 74718 |  1897K|    85   (3)| 00:00:02 |
|*  3 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| SMALL |     1 |     4 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

1 - filter("ID"=45 OR  EXISTS (SELECT /*+ */ 0 FROM "SMALL" "SMALL"

          WHERE "ID"=:B1))

3 - filter("ID"=:B1)
```

Are there any ways in which we can rewrite the Query So that it always goes for index Scan.

Comment: Is that a typo -- thought it'd be an error for using LIKE on a column whose datatype isn't string related (VARCHAR2, etc)

Comment: so you want id's that start with 45?  like 45, 45029, and 451?

Answer (score 3):

No, no and no.

You do NOT want it to use an index. Luckily Oracle is smarter than that.

ID is numeric. While it might have ID values of 45,450,451,452,4501,45004,4500003 etc, in the indexes these values will be scattered anywhere and everywhere. If you went with a condition such as ID BETWEEN 450 AND 459, then it may be worth using the index.

To use the index it would have to scan it all the way from top to bottom (converting each ID to a character to do the LIKE comparison). Then, for any match, it has to go off to get the NAME column.

It has decided that it is easier to and quicker to scan the table (which, with 75,000 rows isn't that big anyway) rather than mucking about going back and forth between the index and the table.

Comment: Spot on.  THe way to do it would be a Function Based Index that converts the ID to a string.  Then LIKE would behave "correctly" for want of a better term.

Answer (score 1):

The others are right, you shouldn't use a numeric column like that.

However, it is actually, the `OR <subquery>` construct that is causing a (performance) problem in this case. I don't know if it is different in version 11, but up to version 10gr2, it causes a a filter operation with what is basically a nested loop with a correlated subquery. In your case, the use of a numeric column as a varchar also results in a full table scan.

You can rewrite your query like this:

```
select *
  from big
 where id like '45%'
union all
select *
  from big
  join small using(id)
 where id not like '45%';
```

With your test case, I end up with a row count of 174000 rows in big and 9 small.
Running your query takes 7 seconds with 1211399 consistent gets.
Running my query 0,7 seconds and uses 542 consistent gets.

The explain plans for my query is:

```
 --------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                     | Name   | Rows  | Cost (%CPU)|
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT              |        |  8604 |   154   (6)|
|   1 |  UNION-ALL                    |        |       |            |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL           | BIG    |  8603 |   151   (4)|
|   3 |   NESTED LOOPS                |        |     1 |     3   (0)|
|*  4 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL          | SMALL  |     1 |     3   (0)|
|   5 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| BIG    |     1 |     0   (0)|
|*  6 |     INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | BIG_PK |     1 |     0   (0)|
---------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter(TO_CHAR("ID") LIKE '45%')
   4 - filter(TO_CHAR("SMALL"."ID") NOT LIKE '45%')
   6 - access("BIG"."ID"="SMALL"."ID")


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
          1  recursive calls
          0  db block gets
        542  consistent gets
          0  physical reads
          0  redo size
      33476  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
        753  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
         76  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          0  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
       1120  rows processed
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this might work:

```
select * 
  from big_table big
 where id like '45%' 
    or exists ( select id from small_table where id = big.id);
```

Comment: Hi Sunil I tried that but got the same result                         Execution Plan
| Id  | Operation          | Name  | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |       |  3737 | 97162 |    85   (3)| 00:00:02 |
|*  1 |  FILTER            |       |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| BIG   | 74718 |  1897K|    85   (3)| 00:00:02 |
|*  3 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| SMALL |     1 |     4 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |